# How to create a custom IntelliJ IDE inspection based on regex?

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, static-analysis, intellij-inspections

Is it possible to create a custom IntelliJ IDEA inspections that detects code matching a certain regex? If so: how?

For example I want to spot places in the code where the key for a lookup in a `Map` is created inside the square brackets:

```
val x = myMap[SomeKey(a, b)]
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I don't ask for "structural search and replace", because that is not available for Kotlin today.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what problem you are trying to solve with such an inspection? Maybe there is a plugin that could help with it.

Comment: @JanThomä I've added the example. The goal is essentially to enforce some coding conventions not yet covered by the available inspections or formatting rules.

Comment: Indeed, all I can find is to create a custom inspection with [structural search and replace](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-custom-inspections.html#) and that doesn't seem to be available for Kotlin. (which is really strange?) So I'm afraid your best bet is to create a plugin with your custom inspection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Structural Search is available [for Kotlin](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tutorial-structural-search-and-replace-in-kotlin.html) since IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3.

However if you are using a language not supported by Structural Search, IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1 now also has [custom RegExp Search & Replace inspections](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2023.1/regex-search-and-replace-inspections.html).